# pandas How to remove all rows that contain all false using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to remove all rows with all zeros.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'b': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'c': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'd': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'e': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'f': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})
```

Using .ix I would do `df.ix[(df>0).any(1)]`

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
1   0   0   0   0   0   1
5   0   0   5   0   0   0
6   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   1   0   0
9   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

to get the correct output but when I try with iloc it gives me `iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available`. I am trying to use iloc because ix is now depreciated.

```
df.iloc[(df>0).any(1)]
```

Comment: ``df.loc[df.any(axis=1)]``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `iloc`

```
df[(df>0).any(1)] # or df.loc[(df>0).any(1)]
Out[185]: 
   a  b  c  d  e  f
1  0  0  0  0  0  1
5  0  0  5  0  0  0
6  1  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  1  0  0
9  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Wow that was really simple, can't believe I missed that. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can iterate the df rows and check if all row values are equal to 0. If this is the case, you drop the corresponding row. For example:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if (all(values == 0 for values in row.values)):
    df=df.drop(index)
```

The above code produces your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `.iloc` here you can just use `df[(df>0).any(1)]`, it will give you the desired output.

However, if you want to do it with `.iloc` here's what to do:
What you are trying to do is pass a pandas Series object to `.iloc`, thus getting an error.

Convert the pandas series to list 1st then pass to `.iloc` i.e. this >>

```
df.iloc[list((df>0).any(1))]
```